# when edittext is empty and button is pressed android application crashes

Tags: android, android-edittext

[image]

When `EditText` is empty and button is pressed android application crashes
if 1 or more edittext is empty and pushing the button causes error.

this is the code:

```
public class Tab4Weight extends  Fragment {
       EditText firstNumber;
       EditText secondNumber;
       TextView addResult;
       Button btnAdd;

       @Override
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab4weight, container, false);

          firstNumber = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.txtNumber1);
          secondNumber = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.txtNumber2);
          addResult = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtResult);
          btnAdd = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
          btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
             String value1= firstNumber.getText().toString();
             String value2= secondNumber.getText().toString();
             int a=Integer.parseInt((value1));
             int b=Integer.parseInt((value2));

             int sum= getCoordinates(a,b);
             Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Weight in Kg: " + 
             String.valueOf(sum),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

          }

          private int getCoordinates (int coordA, int coordB){
              int results = 0;
              if (coordA < 7000 && coordB < 30 && coordB > -45)
              {
                  results = 7400;
              }

              else{
                  if (coordA==8000 && coordB ==30)
                  {
                      results = 7100;
                  }


       firstNumber.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
          @Override
          public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

              }

          @Override
          public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

          }

          @Override
          public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {int jumlah = Integer.parseInt(firstNumber.getText().toString());

          if( firstNumber.getText().toString().equals("")||jumlah > 10001 
           && jumlah < 10999) {
                firstNumber.setText("11000");
                return;
            }
            else {
                if (firstNumber.getText().toString().equals("") || jumlah > 
            11001 && jumlah < 11999) {
                    firstNumber.setText("12000");
                }
                else {
                    if (firstNumber.getText().toString().equals("") || 
             jumlah > 12001 && jumlah < 12999) {
                        firstNumber.setText("13000");
                    }
```

when edittext is empty and button is pressed android application crashes
if 1 or more edittext is empty

can you help me

Comment: Please try to produce a [mcve] of your problem. Also see [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Answer (score 1):

try this you need to check first that your `Edittext` value is empty or not

use  **[isEmpty(CharSequence str)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html)** to check whether your `Edittext` is empty or not

> Returns true if the string is null or 0-length.

```
btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View view) {
              if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(firstNumber.getText().toString())&&!TextUtils.isEmpty(secondNumber.getText().toString())){
                  String value1= firstNumber.getText().toString();
                  String value2= secondNumber.getText().toString();
                  int a=Integer.parseInt((value1));
                  int b=Integer.parseInt((value2));

                  int sum= getCoordinates(a,b);
                  Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Weight in Kg: " +
                          String.valueOf(sum),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              }else {
                  Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "value is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }

          }
      });
```

Comment: thank you There is also a question
when erase number on pressure altitude has been crashed can you give me your email send to you can you help me

Comment: didn't get u @mohamaddamaj

Comment: another question plese same code when erase number on pressure the application has error can you help me plz

Comment: i didn't understand your second question

Comment: i sent you on email with attachment check your email please

Comment: same application on edittext 1 pressure altitude when enter number and erase the application has crashed

Comment: can u share crash log

Comment: i cant share now after 50 min for this i sent you email